# iOS: load file inside folder/directory from AppBundle

Tags: ios, file, loading

I want to load a file from AppBundle. I am able to do this at top level ("/file.txt") with following code:

```
guard let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "file", ofType: "txt") else {
    print("file not found")
    return
}
```

But when I put the "file.txt" in a folder ("anyFolder") I do not know how to read the file from "/anyFolder/file.txt".
The shown code does not work with a nested structure.

Comment: Please look at the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/bundle/1410989-path). At the bottom there are related APIs. And it’s highly recommended to prefer the [URL related API](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/bundle/1411540-url) over string paths.

Answer (score 0):

You should use "url(forResource:withExtension:subdirectory:)"
[Check Apple Document](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1sEHyy-3cV8dI6jEFJV91tM7ISqng-vsR/view?usp=sharing)

```
guard let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "ios", withExtension: ".ovpn")
                  else{
                        print("error")
                        return
                    }
            print("bundle",url.path)
```

[Create urls of ios.file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1sEHyy-3cV8dI6jEFJV91tM7ISqng-vsR/view?usp=sharing)